# Same code+binary gives different results on different machines

Tags: c

I'm running into a problem that I can't figure out. Here are some toy C codes that demonstrate the problems:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
  float theta = 2*PI*i/N;
  double s1 = sin(theta);
  double c1 = cos(theta);

  float s3 = s1;
  float c3 = c1;

  float s2 = sin(theta);
  float c2 = cos(theta);

  printf("theta - %f, (s1:%f, c1:%f) (s2:%f c2:%f) (s3:%f c3:%f) diff (s3-s2:%.8f c3-c2:%.8f)\n", theta, s1, c1, s2, c2, s3, c3, s3-s2, c3-c2);
}
```

I have compiled this with gcc and I'am running the same binary on two machines (both have Intel processors but are different models). Since it's the same binary, I had expect to get the same results, but this is not the case:

e.g., on machine #1, this is one of the out puts:

```
theta - 2.441646, (s1:0.644177, c1:-0.764876) (s2:0.644177 c2:-0.764876) (s3:0.644177 c3:-0.764876) 
diff (s3-s2:0.00000006 c3-c2:-0.00000006)
```

And on machine #2:

```
theta - 2.441646, (s1:0.644177, c1:-0.764876) (s2:0.644177 c2:-0.764876) (s3:0.644177 c3:-0.764876) 
diff (s3-s2:0.00000000 c3-c2:0.00000000)
```

I have got two questions:

- On machine #1, why do not s2/s3 and c2/c3 match up?
- More importantly (for my application, where I need these two machines to produce identical results and this precision difference causes larger differences when they are used in other expressions further down), why are the results in consistent across machines? It is the same binary, so is it the processor that's causing the difference? Some other math library?

I would love some explanation to point me in the right direction, thank you~

Comment: I suggest you to check gcc flags about fast/precise math first. Then it makes sense to look at produced assembler code

Comment: Floating point - you gotta love it.

Comment: Also consider using `double` if you need consistent results to more digits.

Comment: Also, are you statically linking to math lib?

Comment: Are these machines running 32-bit, 64-bit or one of each? Why is this question tagged with C++ and C? Are the machines running the same release of your OS?

Comment: Can ypu post how `PI` and `N` are defined?  Also, what compiler toolchain (for example, what does `gcc --version` say) and command line are you using and on what platform(s).

Comment: is one in 64-bit windows and one in 32-bit windows?

Comment: "I need these two machines to produce identical results" - basically you can't use hardware floating point if that is a condition

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Both running 64-bit OS (@M.M sorry about the tags, new here).

Comment: @MichaelBurr gcc --version is 4.8.4. PI is 3.141592653589793238. N is a copy paste error, sorry (it's the loop condition, == 10000)

Comment: I can see why floating point precision can be hairy - however, I would like to just understand what exactly is causing this difference. Is it the processor architecture or some library? At a loss on how to pinpoint this difference .

Comment: The OS is different, yes. Machine #1 is Ubuntu 14.04, machine #2 is Oracle Linux Server 6.3.

Comment: Can you also post some specific values for `i` where the difference shows?

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors could impact the above result, such as

1. If the two CPU modals have the same instruction sets;
2. If both of the two OSes are either 32-bit or 64-bit;
3. If you have the same version of runtime library installed;
4. Or something else...

So. In theory, if they are the same, the result should be the same...